# Getting response text from server

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the text inside a file in the folder structure of my site using the `Microsoft.XmlHttp`, then compare it with my `version.txt` on my local PC. if the same, it will prompt a message that it contains the same version, else it will display the opposite.

```
URL="http://www.example.org/sites/default/files/version.txt"
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
On Error Resume Next
http.open "GET", URL, False
http.send ""
if http.status = 200 Then
    server_version = http.responseText
End if
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objClientVersion = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\mcgfiles\avp\hash.txt",1)
client_version = objClientVersion.ReadLine

comparison = StrComp(server_version, client_version)
If comparison = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "the same"
Else
    Wscript.Echo "not the same"
End If
```

kinda work, but each time i try to change the contents of the http://www.example.org/sites/default/files/version.txt from my server, this scripts still gets the old value: for example, the values of the http://www.example.org/sites/default/files/version.txt before is 123456, when I run the script it gets the 123456. When I change the value to 654321 and run this script, it still gets the old value which is 123456. Help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable response caching:

```
http.open "GET", URL, False
http.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache,max-age=0"
http.setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
http.send
```

Also, you may want to replace `ReadLine` with `ReadAll`, because the former will only read the first line of the local file, while the HTTP request returns the entire remote file.